# Linux 'Byobu' equivelant for mac

Tags: mac, terminal, unix

So at home ive been a linux user for a while, and frequently use byobu in the terminal. After a little searching I was unable to find anything like it for a mac, which I now have to use at work. I'm curious as to there being any software available to macs that can do this, or has a similar setup.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No need to look for an equivalent. It's available for the Mac. You can quickly and easily install it using the excellent [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) package manager. Once you have Homebrew installed, just type `brew install byobu` from the Terminal. It'll download the source, configure and install it.

Comment: I am not a user of github, but isn't it better to use the official application now that there is one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you asking if it would be better to install Homebrew using the Github application?

Comment: I was thinking of this: http://mac.github.com. But perhaps it does not do the same thing.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. No, it's not the same thing. The Github application is for managing Github code repositories. Homebrew is a package manager for installing and managing applications.

Comment: Excellent! Marking as the answer. I also was trying to think of what the name of homebrew was too. I knew there was a third party package manager for mac but couldnt remember the name. Two birds with one stone. THanks a bunch.

Comment: I just did this but when I ran byobu it said "readlink: illegal option -- f" so I think i'm missing a dependency.  coreutils and tmux are the dependencies I was missing.

Comment: @jrwren I had coreutils and installed tmux but the error still remains because it is trying to use mac readlink. Is there some other step to get it to use the coreutils version? Sorry for dredging this up after a long time..

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to necro an old post, but I am adding my own tricks and hacks that were needed to get this to work, since this is the first result for "byobu on mac".

After performing `brew install byobu`, I encountered the same error that @jrwen encountered. I tried to install both `coreutils` and `tmux`, but it turned out that I had `coreutils` installed. However my `$PATH` was setup in such a way that /usr/local/bin came towards the end so the mac versions were always found first. I fixed this by adding

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

to my `~/.bashrc` and sourcing it.

After this I still got an error saying

```
/usr/local/bin/byobu: line 53: ../Cellar/byobu/blah blah : No such file or directory
```

Not sure what brought this on, but the hack that I used to fix this was to add

```
cd /usr/local/bin
```

To the top of my `/usr/local/bin/byobu` script

It now works!!!

Comment: Sorry for (again) necro an old, but what did you get F2, F3, ... keys to work when using Terminal.app?

Comment: @Mandx on my latest install it works out of the box. Do you need to hold down `fn` and press `f2` or `F3` to get them to work? That might be the default in mac and you can toggle it somewhere..

Comment: @Mandx I am currently using `iTerm`, but was earlier using it with TotalTerminal, which is built on top of `Terminal.app`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I use the function keys as actual `F#`, I use them more that the "utility" keys. The issue was on the Keyboard section on the profile settings: Turns out I imported the Solarized settings from the [Github repo](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized) and it had the keybindings wrong, for instance, the `F2` key had this string `\033[OQ` and I noticed that a friend of mine (who uses TotalTerminal) had `\033OQ` instead. So I changed and it worked perfectly! Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Mandx ah ok, great that it is resolved!